# Android Studio: Exception in plugin GitHub Copiolot (1.2.13.2776)

Tags: android, android-studio, github-copilot

Trying to install and run the GitHub Copilot plugin in Android Studio. I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'com.intellij.ui.dsl.builder.Row com.intellij.ui.dsl.builder.Panel.row$default(com.intellij.ui.dsl.builder.Panel, javax.swing.JLabel, kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1, int, java.lang.Object)'
    at com.github.copilot.github.DeviceLoginForm.descriptionPanel(DeviceLoginForm.kt:60)
    at com.github.copilot.github.DeviceLoginForm.access$descriptionPanel(DeviceLoginForm.kt:18)
    at com.github.copilot.github.DeviceLoginForm$deviceLoginPanel$container$1.invoke(DeviceLoginForm.kt:29)
    at com.github.copilot.github.DeviceLoginForm$deviceLoginPanel$container$1.invoke(DeviceLoginForm.kt:27)
    at com.intellij.ui.dsl.builder.BuilderKt.panel(builder.kt:19)
    at com.github.copilot.ui.component.Panel.panelBuilder(Panel.kt:9)
    at com.github.copilot.github.DeviceLoginForm.deviceLoginPanel(DeviceLoginForm.kt:27)
    at com.github.copilot.github.DeviceLoginForm.<init>(DeviceLoginForm.kt:22)
    at com.github.copilot.github.DeviceLoginDialog.createCenterPanel(DeviceLoginDialog.java:65)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.init(DialogWrapper.java:1296)
    at com.github.copilot.github.DeviceLoginDialog.showDeviceLogin(DeviceLoginDialog.java:30)
    at com.github.copilot.lang.agent.AgentGitHubService.loginInteractive(AgentGitHubService.java:108)
    at com.github.copilot.github.GitHubService.lambda$showLoginNotification$0(GitHubService.java:62)
    at com.intellij.notification.NotificationAction.lambda$createSimpleExpiring$2(NotificationAction.java:62)
    at com.intellij.notification.NotificationAction$Simple.actionPerformed(NotificationAction.java:96)
    at com.intellij.notification.NotificationAction.actionPerformed(NotificationAction.java:33)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.doPerformActionOrShowPopup(ActionUtil.java:315)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.lambda$performActionDumbAwareWithCallbacks$4(ActionUtil.java:294)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performDumbAwareWithCallbacks(ActionUtil.java:337)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAwareWithCallbacks(ActionUtil.java:294)
    at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.IdeUiServiceImpl.performActionDumbAwareWithCallbacks(IdeUiServiceImpl.java:109)
    at com.intellij.notification.Notification.fire(Notification.java:288)
    at com.intellij.notification.impl.NotificationsManagerImpl.lambda$createAction$11(NotificationsManagerImpl.java:841)
    at com.intellij.ui.components.labels.LinkLabel.doClick(LinkLabel.java:174)
    at com.intellij.ui.components.labels.LinkLabel.doClick(LinkLabel.java:388)
    at com.intellij.ui.components.labels.LinkLabel$MyMouseHandler.mouseReleased(LinkLabel.java:361)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:918)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchMouseEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:840)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:763)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$6(IdeEventQueue.java:450)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:791)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$7(IdeEventQueue.java:449)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.performActivity(TransactionGuardImpl.java:113)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.performActivity(IdeEventQueue.java:624)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$8(IdeEventQueue.java:447)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:881)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:493)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Any ideas what is going on here?

Answer (score 6):

The newest GitHub copilot version is having this issue. I fixed it by manually downloading version 1.2.9.2684 here: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/17718-github-copilot/versions/stable

Then you have to Install plugin from disk in the preferences (see the attached image): [image]

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by updrading to Android Studio Flamingo version. Maybe that will help somebody who encounters the same issue.